# how did netflix and other services allow to preload movies etc

Tags: android, ios, encryption, streaming, netflix

I am curious and thinking about the function **netflix, amazon video, disney+ etc.** is using to allow there users to pre-download the movies and watch them offline.

How is that coded? Is it really that simple and just a download?

I think there must be a smarter way like a encrypted way of saving the movies on your device.

anyone a idea or 'know-how' how to implement a feature like this?

Comment: You should learn about Digital Rights Management. Start with [AOSP DRM page](https://source.android.com/devices/drm) and/or search on "Google Widevine"